# How to display correct array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I've created a Java program, and I want to display statistics. 
When the user input `1`, it is single. And when a user input `2`, it is a couple.  When a user input `3`, it is a family of 3.

Heres the example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter group #1: ");
int g1 = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter group #2: ");
int g2 = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter group #3: ");
int g3 = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter group #4: ");
int g4 = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();

int[] numbers = {g1,g2,g3,g4};
int[] count = new int[] { 0, 0, 0};

String[] category = new String[]{"Single", "Couple","Family of 3"};
//String[][] category = new String[][] {{"Single"}, {"Couple"}, {"Family of 3"}};
String a = Arrays.toString(category).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    count[numbers[i] - 1]++;
}

System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Statistic: ");

for (int i=2; i <count.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(a + " : " + count[i]);
}
```

But the display is so weird. Can help?

Results:

```
run:
Enter group #1: 1
Enter group #2: 1
Enter group #3: 1
Enter group #4: 1

Statistic: 
Single, Couple, Family of 3 : 4
Single, Couple, Family of 3 : 0
Single, Couple, Family of 3 : 0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Correct results should be:

```
run:
Enter group #1: 1
Enter group #2: 1
Enter group #3: 1
Enter group #4: 1

Statistic: 
Single : 4
Couple: 0
Family of 3 : 0
```

Comment: You are not storing count properly.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
for (int i=2; i <count.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(a + " : " + count[i]);
}
```

should be

```
for (int i=0; i <count.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(category[i] + " : " + count[i]);
}
```

and get rid of variable `a`.

Comment: @Hakim Lewis - Could you accept this answer since it worked for you. Thanks.